# Golang Unmarshal same level XML elements into array

Tags: arrays, xml, go, encoding, children

I have XML that I would like to unmarshal the address info into its on array as part of my struct:

```
<customer>
    ...
    <dob>1990-10-01</dob>
    <address1>555 Hollywood Blvd</address1>
    <city>Hollywood</city>
    <state>CA</state>
    <zipCode>99999</zipCode>
    <alternateAddress1>575 Hollywood St</alternateAddress1>
    <alternateCity>Los Angeles</alternateCity>
    <alternateState>CA</alternateState>
    <alternateZipCode>12345</alternateZipCode>
    ....
</customer>
```

My attempt at a struct:

```
    type Test struct {
      CustProfile struct {
        DOB string `xml:"birthDate" json:"dob"`
        Address []struct {
            PrimaryAddress struct {
                Street string `xml:"address1" json:"line1"`
                City string `xml:"city" json:"city"`
                State string `xml:"state" json:"state"`
                ZipCode string `xml:"zipCode" json:"zip"`
                IsPrimaryAddress string `json:"isPrimaryAddress"`
            }
            AlternateAddress struct {
                Street string `xml:"alternateAddress1" json:"line1"`
                City string `xml:"alternateCity" json:"city"`
                State string `xml:"alternateState" json:"state"`
                ZipCode string `xml:"alternateZipCode" json:"zip"`
                IsPrimaryAddress string `json:"isPrimaryAddress"`
            }
        } `json:"address"`
    } `xml:"customer" json:"custProfile"`
  }
```

So I'm having a couple of issues here. The first issue is that all the elements are in the same level and from what I figured out so far, since the CustProfile struct is already associated with the **customer** parent element, I'm not able to reference any child elements inside the Address struct because the path would be **customer->?>city,state,etc** which will always return null since that path doesn't exist.

The second issue is the way I'm trying to define a default string for **IsPrimaryAddress**. I tried doing something like this but I'm getting an undefined error.

```
var marshalTest Test
...
marshalTest.CustProfile.Address.PrimaryAddress.IsPrimaryAddress = "Y";
marshalTest.CustProfile.Address.AlternateAddress.IsPrimaryAddress = "N";
```

Is it possible to unmarshal this XML into a struct that results in the struct below?

```
{
  "custProfile": {
    "dob": "1990-10-01",
    "address": [
      {
        "line1": "555 Hollywood Blvd",
        "city": "HOLLYWOOD",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "99999",
        "isPrimaryAddress": "Y"
      },
      {
        "line1": "575 Hollywood St",
        "city": "LOS ANGELES",
        "state": "CA",
        "zip": "12345",
        "isPrimaryAddress": "N"
      }
    ]
}
```

I'm not at all that familiar with XML encoding in Go and the best I've been able to manage is this:

```
 {
      "custProfile": {
        "dob": "1990-10-01",
        "address": null
      }
 }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: In your sample code, `Test.CustProfile.Address` is a slice, which is why you're getting an undefined error trying to read `marshalTest.CustProfile.Address.PrimaryAddress` - you have to specify an element of the slice to operate on. In your sample, each element of the slice has both a `PrimaryAddress` and `SecondaryAddress`, which I don't think is what you're trying to do. However, I don't know any way to do what you're describing using `xml.Unmarshal` directly; you'll have to do some manipulation to get there.

Comment: Hi @Adrian, what type of manipulation are you referring to? I'm really new to Go so I don't know the extent of what all can be done. Thanks

Comment: Unmarshal it as two members of the same type, then add both to a slice of the type after unmarshaling.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to use a combination of xml parsing with [Xquery](https://github.com/antchfx/xquery) and json parsing with [Gabs](https://github.com/Jeffail/gabs) to manually construct the struct I wanted. Probably not the cleanest solution but it allowed me to customize the struct to the degree I wanted.